# check if IP in my network have listener on specific port

Tags: c#, sockets, server

I made a game with multiplayer game in local network, and I want players view all game room  available in  local network

How to do this trick without check ping all IP in my local network with specific port, Because it takes a lot of time??

Comment: online game usually use a central server, or a service, everytime a client  "opens" a room, he registers the room in the service. when ever you want to get list of available rooms, you query that service. behind the scenes the service can "ping" that room's details to verify availability. if success add to the list, if not, dont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is scanning the whole subnet.

Another alternative is to broadcast/multicast a query message on the subnet and implement a responder in your game that responds to this query with it's IP address. The responding nodes are the ones you need to talk to directly.

Comment: how can scanning the whole subnet in few time ?

Comment: Scanning may take long time. The second alternative is the one I would go with.

Comment: how can do Method 2 ?
Can you give me an example pl?

Comment: For example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1705/IP-Multicasting-in-C

Comment: Thankssssssss you 
udp broadcast is the best way